# Disable user input with materialize css autocomplete

Tags: css, materialize

I was wondering if there is a way to disable to user input in an input field with Materialize css autocomplete, if the user does not select a value from the dropdown?

[Link to documentaition](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)

Comment: add "disabled" to the input with class of "autocomplete" and give a try

Comment: Please post the necessary html markup.